# Password protection for a page with a simple function - what are the downsides?

Tags: javascript, passwords, e-commerce, password-protection, bigcommerce

I am doing work on an e-commerce platform, and I was asked to come up with a solution so that a certain group of customers could enter a password protected page on the site.  The platform doesn't allow for this, as in the functionality is not available, so according to customer support, it's something you would have to create a custom template for and build from scratch. It doesn't need to be fancy, or hacker proof, just secure *enough*. So instead of doing that, I dropped the script below into the body of the page.

My first version: I use a prompt to ask for an input (password).  If you click "prevent this page from creating additional dialouges", it creates sort of an infinite reload loop for that tab (not ideal, but problem?). Are there other serious problems?  Easy hacks for your average person?

```
$("body").hide();

var passwordCheckFunction = function() {

        var testPassword = window.prompt("YOU SHALL NOT PASS");

        if (testPassword === "thisPredefinedPassword") {
            $("body").show();
        } else {
            location.reload();
        }
    };
    passwordCheckFunction();
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, and thank you for your time.

Comment: You can try adding a header to every page which needs a check just like login functionality. If the person is logged in, you can allow him to enter.

Comment: *"Easy hacks for your average person?"* - Well having the password hardcoded in plain text doesn't even require a "hack" to uncover. Anyone who has any idea about the browser's "view source" option could see your code.

Comment: actually while prompt is open, it doesn't allow you to view source, if you disable prompt and inspect, it does not show the function or the hardcoded password.  I don't know if there is a way to inspect further or go deeper, but I would think that falls under the category of average-person-proof. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, if you type `$("body").show()` in console, that will show the page. Your javascript function is doing exact same thing. So you cannot implement it on the back end?

Comment: Use StormPath. It probably has some way to integrate with your back end. https://stormpath.com

Comment: Interesting Petr!  I tried it several ways:  Open inspector then load page, shows body but doesn't get rid of prompt -- load page, cancel prompt, manually stop reload, inspect, but when I type $("body").show(); is gives me this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of null(…)"      When you say implement on the backend, what exactly do you mean? This function? It's an e-commerce platform and there are hundreds of template and panel layouts, I'm not really sure where I would put it so that it only worked on this page. (I've only been coding for a year :/  )

Comment: What language are you using on the backend? PHP or anything else?

Comment: I'm using Javascript. When you say 'back end' I'm not 100% sure what you are referring to.  It's an e-commerce platform so I'm used to everyone calling anything with a symbol in it, the back end.  I could create a JS file and stick it in there, but I'm not sure how I would target that specific page only.

Comment: JavaScript is a frontend language. You might be using something else also to call the paths/APIs/or process requests. Can you please tell all the technologies you're using in this project? PHP/Node/JSP or anything else?

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for that.  I haven't touched any PHP and I probably wouldn't trust myself with it at this point but I just looked through all the files in the repo, and I didn't see any .php.  I was more just trying to come up with a safe and relatively simple solution.  Its Bigcommerce, so its their own framework/template but customized in certain areas (only with JS). I was under the impression that JS was used for the API calls and whatnot (by my predecessor), but as I said, I am relatively new, sorry for that.

Comment: It's alright @Tron. I can't be sure about a custom template for eCommerce but there might be something to restrict a page to some selected users only with a login form or something, you can implement that. If it's there you can:

1. Create an index page asking for login
2. If your user is allowed, redirect him/her to the customer support page else somewhere else.

Try to see the documentation of framework you're using. Also for help in web technologies you can see this link http://blog.udacity.com/2014/12/front-end-vs-back-end-vs-full-stack-web-developers.html

Comment: Thanks a bunch Pratyush, I really appreciate the help.  Unfortunately the platform doesn't have that capability which is what brought me here, but I'm glad it happened!  The platform tries to be user-friendly for non-coders, and in doing so makes things much more of a hassle for programmers.  The best I can do with their software is hide the page and give someone a link, but that wouldn't be secure enough, anyone could go if they knew what they were looking for.

Comment: To clarify for others, the ecommerce platform is SaaS based so there's no backend access.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your secret page as a category.
2. Customize it to your heart's desire by [choosing a custom template
   file for it](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Creating-Custom-Template-Files).
3. Finally, restrict it to only the authorized customer group
   by removing it from view from guests and every group except the
   authorized one. 
   [image]
   [image]

Using this method, the customer only has to sign into his/her own customer account. BigCommerce will prevent access to the page by reading the assigned customer group of the customer.

Comment: Just to remind anyone that, at least now there's a "Customer Group for Guests" dropdown by the trash bin button that needs to be also changed to actually enable Guests to be added to that Customer Group. :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn't your desired method, but you might consider instead just making your page inactive in the admin area of your BC store, then instead of a password provide the direct url for users that are able to see that page.

I'm not sure about the implications for google indexing with an inactive page, but I would assume that they are set not to index it, and if not you could set it in robots.txt

Comment: When you do that, to my knowledge it just sends you to a page that "can not be found'  -  and if you make it so that it's just a 'hidden' page, anyone with a link, or who knows what they are looking for, can get to it,

Comment: Inactive categories result in "can not be found" but pages are accessible with the correct url. But you're right, if they know the url they will be able to find the page. I also like the suggestion to restrict it using customer groups as suggested by @love